# How do you send a post via XMLhttprequest to my own Node server in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I am trying to send data to node via a XMLhttprequest. The data looks like this (/q/zmw:95632.1.99999.json). My connection to Node is correct, however, I was getting an empty object so I set the headers to Content-Type application/json and then stringified the data. However Node gives me a Unexpected token " error. I presume it is because of the string, however, if I don't stringify the data then it errors out because of the "/" in the data. How do i properly send the data using pure Javascript. I want to stay away from axios and jquery because I want to become more proficient in vanilla javascript. I will make the final call to the api in node by assembling the url prefix and suffix.

Here is my code:

```
function getCityForecast(e){

     //User selects option data from an early JSONP request.
     var id = document.getElementById('cities');
     var getValue = id.options[id.selectedIndex].value;

     //Assembles the suffix for http request that I will do in Node.
     var suffix = getValue + ".json";
     var string = JSON.stringify(suffix);

     console.log(suffix);

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/", true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     xhr.send(string);
}
```

Node.js code:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var path = require('path');
 var request = require('request');
 var http = require('http');

 // ****************** Middle Ware *******************
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('working');

    console.log(req.body);
 });

 app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('listening')});
```

Comment: See the `FormData` object for putting data in proper format for the POST request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects or using nothing but `XMLHttpRequest` see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

Comment: This looks like it will successfuly create a string containing a filename, JSON encode it, then send it to your server with the correct HTTP headers. I don't know what data you are *trying* to send, and you haven't shared the server side code which is where your error is coming from. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: You do not send a request to Node.js, you send it to an HTTP server and the request does not care if that one is a node, java, go server or a reverse proxy.

Comment: @Quentin thank you a lot  for the question. I had forgotten to actually create an object to stringify. I realized when you stated "create a string containing a filename" that I was only creating a string and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my mistake and this was my problem. I was trying to send a string instead of an object. So it wasn't proper JSON like this:

```
   var string = JSON.stringify(suffix);
```

To remedy the situation I added:

```
var newObj = JSON.stringify({link : suffix});
```

This allowed my post to be successful because I was now sending an object hence the word Javascript Object Notation.

Answer (score -2):

This is working for me, at the moment.  The REST API I'm hitting requires a token.  Yours might not, or it might be looking for some other custom header.  Read the API's documentation.  Note, you might need a polyfill/shim for cross browser-ness (promises).  I'm doing GET, but this works for POST, too.  You may need to pass an object.  If you're passing credentials to get a token, don't forget `window.btoa`.  Call it like:

```
httpReq('GET', device.address, path, device.token).then(function(data) {
  //console.log(data);
  updateInstrument(deviceId,path,data);
}, function(status) {
  console.log(status);
});


  function httpReq(method, host, path, token) {
    if(method === "DELETE" || method === "GET"|| method === "POST" || method === "PUT" ){
      var address = 'https://' + host + path;
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, address, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("X-auth-token", token);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var status = xhr.status;
          if (status == 200 || status == 201 || status == 202) {
            resolve(xhr.response);
          }
          // this is where we catch 404s and alert what guage or resource failed to respond
          else {
            reject(status);
          }
        };
        xhr.send();
      });
    } else {
      console.log('invalid method');
    }
  };
```